# How to Use Resposive Tables in WordPress ADMIN Pages?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, table

I have created a custom ADMIN page using `add_menu_page`.

There is a HTML table in that page. 
I need to make it responsive.

Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not extend WP_List_Table? It creates responsive tables that collapse to an accordion when the table width exceeds the screen size.

See [Class Reference/WP List Table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table).

You might take a look at the code in this plugin to get started:
[Custom List Table Example](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/)

Answer (score -1):

You can make tables responsive using CSS. I recommend applying a class to the , and referencing that class in CSS code setting dimensions to percentages. ...Something like  will respond very well to .respond {width:100%; height: 100%}. If you want the responsiveness to be really awesome, you can address different devices explicitly in CSS using media queries. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/