# Is there alternative to WP_List_Table?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, table

I need to create html tables in a admin pages. It should be responsive.

After a research I find the WP_List_Table.

But in codex page,

This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.

So I can't use it. What is the alternative for it? Or is there any way to creat responsive tables in WP admin area?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Resposive Tables in WordPress ADMIN Pages?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226127/how-to-use-resposive-tables-in-wordpress-admin-pages)

Answer (score 2):

My choice would be to use `WP_List_Table`.  If you continue reading the Codex it makes it clear that it is commonly used by third party code. "Someday" it might go away, but I doubt it will happen abruptly (if at all).  If it does change, there will probably be a newer solution to replace it.

EDIT:
Another thought.  if you feel really can't use `WP_List_Table` the answer is in your question: "If you would still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and distribute with your own project,...".

Just give it your own class name, then it will never go away.